# Shiro redirecting back to login page after wrong/false credentials(username/password)

Tags: java, security, filter, shiro

**Q1:** ***How can I redirect*** to unauthenticated url(or any page/way to say user that credentials were incorrect) ***after credentials entered incorrectly***.

**Q2:** ***What is the normal/default behaviour for shiro*** when credentials are incorrect? (does it send -back to login, -unauthorized page, -some message)

**INFO:** shiro integration with spring. I use my own credentials. 
And I have tried to throw IncorrectCredentialsException, WebApplicationException in doGetAuthenticationInfo method of MyRealm when username/password is wrong. 
No help. I debugged and it's using MyRealm when login form posted.(debug stopped in doGetAuthenticationInfo method of my Realm)

Here is part of my spring **settings** for shiro

```
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login.html"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/rest/security/redirect"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/unauthorized.html"/>

    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value>
            /login.html = authc
            /logout = logout
            /apps/admin/** = authc, roles[admin]
```

**Note**: settings for web.xml and others are configured. Authentication, authorization and any other redirects working as a charm except login redirect after wrong credentials.

Comment: Please share the answer, if you found any

Comment: @AfilAnsari I couldn't get it work and leave it as it was. I will try today too. If you find answer please don't forget to answer.

Comment: According to the documentation, the default behaviour for the FormAuthenticationFilter is to redirect back to hte loginUrl

Have you found an aswer to your first question?